# UDP socket problem

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, winsock, client-server

I'm writing a multiplayer game (obviously using UDP sockets. note: using winsock 2.2). The server code reads something like this:

```
while(run)
{
    select(0, &readSockets, NULL, NULL, &t)
    if(FD_ISSET(serverSocket, &readSockets))
    {
        printf("%s\n","Data receieved");
        //recvfrom over here
    }
    FD_SET(serverSocket, &readSockets);
}
```

While this is not receiving data from my client, this is:

```
recvfrom(serverSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, &client, &client_size);
```

Comment: and what is the problem? why don't you use recvfrom - which is the canonical way to read from UDP sockets?

Comment: @eli - because I don't want it to block, as the server console has to refresh too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... after fiddling with the code a bit, I found these lines:

```
console->clear();
console->resetCursorPosition();
```

So, it **was** receiving data, but the message on the console was getting erased instantly. [sigh]

Answer (score 1):

One possible issue here is possibly the `select()` call.  I believe the first parameter needs to be the highest socket number +1.

Comment: Quoting the winsock documentation : Parameter 1 : nfds - included for the sake of backwards compatibility

Comment: You will need that it you want it to work on non-Windows systems.  With just one socket it would be `serverSocket + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

The `FD_SET` is at the end of the loop so it looks like your first call to `select()` may have an empty or uninitialized fd_set.  Make sure you use `FD_ZERO(&readSockets)` and `FD_SET(serverSocket, &readSockets)` before your loop.  Also it would be good to check for errors on the `select()` call.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to check for errors returned by `select()`. On Windows this would be something like:

```
if (( nret = select( nfds, &rset, &wset, &eset, &to )) == SOCKET_ERROR )
{
   // error handling, probably with WSAGetLastError()
   // ...
}
```

Since it looks like you are using a timeout, `select()` can also return zero, i.e. no socket descriptors are ready, but timeout expired.